# Simulate table behaviour "expand to all remaning space" (a filler) with a div (height I mean)

Tags: css

Is what I state in the table possible with css3?
In css2 you can't replicate directly that behaviour and is really boring, you have to do a lot of workarounds for something that already exists.

Here is the image I'm working on (the image is clickable to zoom in):
[image: Website image]

I'm trying to make that dark grey part to fill everything between the 2 green parts. How to make it?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Could you post the table markup that specifies what you want your CSS to do?

Comment: I posted an image, if possible I would like to avoid post the CSS because is big.

Comment: I don't know why so many downvotes for this question but well doesn't matter, I found the solution on google

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't downvote, but you can always expect downvotes when your question contains a rant.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I'll avoid a rant, but when you lose 3 hours doing something like that you really go mad. I hate CSS some times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in an interesting article: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-top-and-bottom-frames-layout/

I found that link from here: http://csscreator.com/node/11049

The important part is this one:

```
#framecontentTop, #framecontentBottom{
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 130px; /*Height of top frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}

#framecontentBottom{
top: auto;
bottom: 0; 
height: 110px; /*Height of bottom frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white;
}

#maincontent{
position: fixed; 
top: 130px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 110px; /*Set bottom value to HeightOfBottomFrameDiv*/
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
}

* html #maincontent{ /*IE6 hack*/
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}
```

Expecially using position: fixed and top: auto (never used I don't also understand very well what does it means).